# Indent all lines after the first line in the second paragraph of a section

Tags: indentation

I would like to indent all lines of the second paragraph of a section to match the first indented line. An example is below:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\hangindent=0.35cm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Currently, I am using `\hangindent=0.35cm` at the start of the second paragraph which looks like what I want. However, I am not sure if `0.35` is equal to the default indentation of the first line. Is there another way to make sure the correct indentation space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\setlength{\hangindent}{\parindent}
```

in place of `hangindent=0.35cm`.